# What are some examples of some difficult Unit Tests, that were either impossible or solved creatively?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I am in the process of writing Unit tests for our core library.

One of the classes measures workload on the computer performance over time (as an average), applies some weights and can spit out a number.

Now, the class it uses to do the averages and apply weights is easily unit testable.  (Throw some averages in, compare against a known result).  What is not so easy to test is the *purpose* of the `Workload` class itself, as that would involve forcing the machine to be at, say, 50% utilisation, and then checking against the known, weight-adjusted average for 50%.

I am aware, of course, that I can "pretend" the machine is at 50% utilisation and compare results that way, but at no point is the unit test actually being tested against 50% real utilisation.

What other "difficult" test-cases have you come across, and if they are not impossible, what creative methods did you employ to solve it?

Comment: can't you force a workload? get it to do some bitcoin mining on half the cores, or something...

Comment: @MarcGravell, not just the cores.. it uses 3 performance counters: Disk, CPU & User... not sure where I'd start on that :)

Comment: How does Workload figure out "utilisation"? I suspect it uses another class to do that. In which case a Unit test is easy. Mock/Fake/Stub out the "utilisation" class. If it does not have an interface, wrap it up in an adaptor pattern so that has an interface...

Comment: @aron, it uses the `PerformanceCounter` class to do the work.

Comment: @Moo-Juice, being rhetorical. Anyways. Unit Testing and what is hard is well documented. In practice, Unit Testing is hard (read impossible) when there are non-deterministic elements. The classic examples are UI, State Machines and Databases. Modern design patterns have tried to ring fence these away from our lovely Testable code. Prime example would be the MVVM pattern employed by WPF best practices.

Comment: @aron, can you expand on that as an answer?  I think it is beneficial to the community as a whole.  Anyone who turns to writing unit tests to make sure code is good is going to run in to this eventually.  I was trying to start more of a discussion on *what* is difficult to unit test against, and why.  There may also be cases where someone is scratching their head, but unbeknownst to them - the solution is trivial, or not far off.

Comment: Will work on something...need sleep now...

Comment: @Aron how are state machines non-deterministic?

Comment: @David clarification. A state machine that isn't scoped to the test, for example a singleton that keeps track of http requests in flight on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever tried testing that a simple `MsgBox` (or any modal window, for that matter) gets displayed in a WinForms application? On a recent project we spent a while fighting with Win32 handles and multi-threaded test cases trying to consistently verify the dialog showed up on screen (since it's modal, you can't just execute it from your main test thread). The tests would work some of the time, but were very prone to intermittent failure for no "good" reason (e.g. the window lost focus during the test due to some background process).

In this case, we used the power of C# delegates to essentially mock the static call to `MsgBox.Show()`. By declaring a delegate such as

```
public delegate DialogResult ShowDelegate(string text, string caption);
```

we could use `new ErrorMessageHelper(MsgBox.Show)` in production, and the tests looked something like

```
[TestFixture]
public class ErrorDialogHelperTest
{
    [Test]
    public void UsesShowDelegateToDisplayMessage()
    {
        bool delegateWasCalled = false;
        ShowDelegate mockShowDelegate = delegate(string text, string caption)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("the expected message", text);
            Assert.AreEqual("the expected title", caption);
            delegateWasCalled = true;
        };

        ErrorDialogHelper helper = new ErrorDialogHelper(showDelegate);

        helper.ShowErrorMessage("the expected message", "the expected title");
        Assert.IsTrue(delegateWasCalled);
    }
}
```

We of course had further tests to verify that we did indeed construct the production instances with `MsgBox.Show`. I'm using `MsgBox` in this example, but we used a similar technique to test the displaying of all our modal windows.

Another classic difficult-to-test example is when your code needs to consume wall clock dates and times. Again, the solution is to introduce a fake clock which you can control from your tests. In both these cases, you're relying on the underlying framework or system implementation to work correctly and only test that everything got hooked up properly. Whether that's a reasonable risk or not should be determined case-by-case.

Comment: your Delegate approach is a good example of Dependency Injection.  FYI, addressing your example, Microsoft has created the Moles framework to provide a DI path without having to actually modify framework classes like MsgBox.